# Invalid scope was provided - scope 'subscription'. Please provide the following scope: '/subscriptions/{subscriptionId

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

Here is my code, I using Azure bicep. I have provided the scope but I am getting an error

```
targetScope = 'subscription'


param subscription_id_dataplatform string='sub_id' 

param name_law string = 'default'
param scope_law string = 'subscription'
param workspaceId string = 'object id // law 


module law_module '2.law.bicep'={
  name: name_law
  params:{
    name_law:name_law
    scope_law:scope_law
    workspaceId:workspaceId
  }
  scope:subscription(subscription_id_dataplatform)
  
}
```

**Error**

And the error on this scope

```
scope:subscription(subscription_id_dataplatform)
```

**[{"code":"InvalidInput","message":"Invalid scope was provided - scope 'subscription'. Please provide the following scope: '/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}'"}]}]}]}}**

Comment: Can you confirm you are passing this parameter: `subscription_id_dataplatform` and it is not empty or null ?

Comment: Can you try passing scope as `scope:'subscription/${subscription_id_dataplatform}'`. @bizimunda

Answer (score 0):

> **[{"code":"InvalidInput","message":"Invalid scope was provided - scope 'subscription'. Please provide the following scope: '/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}'"}]}]}]}}**:

After a workaround for the above error, I found that the following changes are required to resolve the issue and make it work as expected.

To begin, when providing any `scope value` to the bicep code, you must provide the complete scope as a string.

You are passing `scope_law` as a `'subscription'`, which doesn't seem to be the proper way to do so. Instead, provide it as

```bash
param  scope_law  string = '/subscriptions/subscription_Id/resourceGroups/resource_group/providers/Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/jaanuwd'
```

The second is the scope that you are using in module code. If we pass it as below manner it should work.

```bash
scope: subscription(subscription_id_dataplatform)
```

However, considering the error message it is throwing,  try passing it as

```
scope:'subscription/${subscription_id_dataplatform}'
```

to make it work without any errors.

*I modified your code as below:*

```bash
targetScope = 'subscription'
param  location  string = 'EastUS'
param  subscription_id_dataplatform  string=''
param  name_law  string = 'default'
param  scope_law  string = '/subscriptions/subscription_ID/resourceGroups/resource_group/providers/Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/jaanuwd'
param  workspaceId  string = 'Workspace_ID'
module  law_module  'laws.bicep' = {
  name: name_law
  params:{
  location: location
 }
scope: 'subscription/${subscription_id_dataplatform}/'
}
```

*Output:*

[image]

[image]

And as @Thomas mentioned in comments, make sure that the `subscription_id_dataplatform` parameter which you are passing is not null.